# Can't auto update R file and something wrong with it

Tags: android

Recently, in my project, `R` file is not auto updated, and each times I change something in my project, i have to build the project myself. In addition, each time I want to use anything in `R` file, I have to insert `pakage` like this: `at.tutorial.R.layout.main` instead of `R.layout.main` as before.
What is my problem? Can anyone give me a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you're importing the correct R file, which would be your.package.name.R, and not android.R  Sometimes in my editor android.R gets automatically imported, which causes the same or a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove         `import android.R` from your code if it is there.

And in Eclipse, go to Project -> Build Automatically so that you dont have to manually build it every time and then try cleaning your project a few times by Project -> Clean.

Answer (score 1):

**`i have to build the project myself.`**

In your Eclipse's project menu there is "Build Automatically" please make it checked so every time your R file get updated.

**`I have to insert pakage like this: at.tutorial.R.layout.main instead of R.layout.main`**

You have to give package name in AndroidManifest.xml file like below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="at.tutorial"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check all of your XML,
2. Project -> Clean,
3. Right click -> Fix Project Properties,
4. Repeat.
5. Maybe try restarting Eclipse

My panic list for R generation problems